# Is there a convention for indicating the new lines, when writing a multi-line quote of a few words on one line?

Tags: writing-style

I wanted to quote something like:

> Happy Birthday
> Had a good time
> See you next year!

However, I wanted it all on one line rather than creating a block quote out of it.

I tried

> Happy Birthday | Had a good time | See you next year!

I wonder if there is an established way to indicate the new lines?

Comment: No law yet against: Happy Birthday. Had a good time. See you next year! Doesn't indicate new lines, but so what? I owe someone the whole graphic layout? No, I don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MLA standard does indeed include rules for separating lines for poetry, used when quoting 3 or fewer lines: use "/" to separate lines, or "//" to separate stanzas, see [Purdue University's guide to MLA formatting](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/mla_style/mla_formatting_and_style_guide/mla_formatting_quotations.html). If you are quoting more than 3 lines, use a block quote.

Comment: And the slash is used much more widely than just in the MLA standard.